# Compare Two PDF File in vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, c#-4.0

I am working on pdf file in vb.net. I want to compare two pdf files. 
Is there any dll that is used for this purpose?

Comment: What kind of comparison are you looking at? What have you tried?

Comment: Not sure, you can refer below URL 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145657/tool-to-compare-large-numbers-of-pdf-files

Comment: Same problem kindly help me to compare text two pdf files. Thanks

Comment: I need to compare text in two different files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ABCpdf to do a lot of things with PDFs. It works very well.

However, there is an inherent problem with comparing PDFs, as they are not always very well structured. But, for example, if your PDFs have form fields, you can quite easily compare the form field values with [ABCpdf](http://www.websupergoo.com/).

Here is a post that shows how to get the text from a PDF with ABCpdf:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10998043/392362

Comment: Is there any third party dll that is used to compare two PDF files? I am ready to buy

Comment: As I said, ABCpdf is a great third party dll for all things regarding PDF. I have used it for many years. But you need to define how you want to compare the files. Do you want to compare text content? Then what if the formatting is slightly different. These are decisions YOU have to make. No third party dll can make those decisions for you.

Comment: First of all really thanks Niels second kindly tell me some more things which we can do from the ABCpdf.  
1) Can we convert Non Searchable PDF to Searchable PDF
2) Can we Highlight some text in the PDF
3) Can you please provide some sample application for PDF file comparison and return result in PDF File.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Samar, I have only used ABCpdf to open a PDF and analyze the contents - and to generate a new PDF (not relevant to you). You do that programmatically, so unfortunately I know nothing about highlighting text etc. However, the link I put in my answer shows you an example of how to use ABCpdf to get the text. You can use that for comparison of text.

Comment: I see your comment "I need to compare text in two different files". As per that comment, you can follow the link I posted to use ABCpdf to compare text in the two files.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare for exact match you could simply calculate and compare their [SHA1 checksums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993903/how-do-i-do-a-sha1-file-checksum-in-c).

Comment: Is there any third party dll that is used to compare two PDF files? I am ready to buy