# Printing PDF with Multiple Pages source formula

Tags: pdf, abcpdf

I used the answer to the below question in mycode which prints a multi page PDF. In the answer why do you divide the cropbox width/height by 72 ?

I have similar code but on certain pages the text at the top of the page is cut of when printed.

I can fix the issue by changing the code to 75, but I would like to understand the formula more first.

[Printing PDF with Multiple Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16327712/printing-pdf-with-multiple-pages/39250947#39250947)

Answer (score 0):

72 is the default DPI (dots per inch) for abcPDF. See http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/source/5-abcpdf/xrendering/2-properties/dotsperinch.htm